# a secure way to access my pages

Tags: php

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to solve an error in this code. I'm following a video tutorial.

```
//when your looking for path
$core_path= dirname(__FILE__);
if(empty($_GET['page']) && in_array("{$_GET['page']}.page.inc.php",scandir("{$core_path}/pages"))==false){
    echo'invalid page';
}
```

The error I get when i try testing this code on my wamp server is

```
Notice: Undefined index: page in C:\wamp\www\pm_system\core\init.inc.php on line 8
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET['page']` 
  Here the name of variable is "page". Make sure that you gave the name of variable to this URL is "page".

For example

```
header("Location:second.php?page=3");// here the name of varible which is passing to the url is "page"
```

on second.php

```
echo $_GET['page'];//give out put 3
```

Comment: I tried using || instead of && in that is, if(empty($_GET['page']) || in_array("{$_GET['page']}.page.inc.php",scandir("{$core_path}/pages"))==false) an action that solved the undefined index page error. but the problem is i get the error invalid page when the pages actually exist

Comment: so by using || it should be work.are you still getting error?

Comment: check that are you getting the value of $_GET['page']; echo $_GET['page'];

Comment: print the array and check are you getting the values. i think your problem is on another page by which the values is coming so first chk are you getting the values on those page?

Comment: if i use print_r(scandir("{$core_path}/pages")); i get resulsts of my pages. that is   Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => inbox.page.inc.php [3] => login.page.inc.php [4] => logout.page.inc.php [5] => new_conversation.page.inc.php [6] => view_conversation.page.inc.php )

Comment: look you are getting the correct path but as i told you check the previous file from the control is coming may be there is problem.

Comment: Iam confused because the other pages are blank, and am just begining the tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a URL without a `$page=some-page`, so the `$_GET['page']` doesn't exist, you should check if it exists instead of if it is empty, like this:

```
//when your looking for path
$core_path= dirname(__FILE__);

if(isset($_GET['page']) && in_array("{$_GET['page']}.page.inc.php",scandir(" {$core_path}/pages"))==false){
    echo'invalid page';
}
```